# Can't log in with admin, no error messages

Tags: joomla-3.x

It looks like that I can't log in to my Joomla back end anymore. No error messages are shown, the log in screen just stays there. If I enter a wrong password on purpose, I get a warning that the username and password doesn't match.

All I did was that I made a backup of **/components/com_users** directory with a different name and deleted the original. I noticed that I made an error since I couldn't log in anymore and copied the directory back with the original **com_users** name. After this I couldn't log in either.

How do I fix my mistake?

Comment: Check the spelling, eg. `com_users` vs. `com_user`. Joomla relies on the naming to find the classes to load for internal processes.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, unfortunately `com_user` was just my writing typo. Just to be sure, I duplicated the directory so that I now have `com_user` and `com_users` but still no luck

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I just upgraded to Joomla 3.8.10, as well as Community Builder and RSMembership. Then, I had the same problem of logging into the back end and front end. I still cannot pinpoint exactly how the plg_user_joomla was disabled in the extensions table, but at least it's fixed. Posting my steps here in case others experience the same scenario.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with these exact symptoms, and the culprit turned out to be that $cookie_domain was defined in configuration.php, and it had the wrong domain.

(This was a staging site, this site was a subdomain of the main domain.)

Setting $cookie_domain to '' or the correct domain fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my problem. [this](https://www.itoctopus.com/login-to-joomla-administrator-not-working-and-no-error-is-displayed) article helped me. The problem was solved by going to phpMyAdmin and searching for `plg_user_joomla` and changing it's `enabled` bit to 1.

Joomla probably disabled the *user* module when I tried to log in without the `com_users` component.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but after trying lot of things I found out that on my server **php version was changed from 5.6 to newer 7.x** version, and my version of joomla requires version 5.x. After I changed it back to 5.6 everything started to work as it was earlier.

So make sure that **php version on server is supported by your version of joomla.**

It is confusing that in most cases you can open your webpage and login administrator page, but can't login just because php version is not supported!

UPDATE

If you discover that this is problem, after you downgrade php version and joomla starts to work, then **you should upgrade your joomla to newest version and then update php version on the server!** 
Using updated php and joomla is very importat because you will get improved security and performance. (just to mention that old joomla sites can be easily hacked… and php 7.x is about 50% faster than 5.x…)

Comment: I am happy that you managed to remedy your issue and thank you for sharing your insight, but advising others to downgrade their php version is not best practice -- it is more of a workaround.  Using an up to date php version is not just important to enable better processing power and speed, it is also a matter of improved security.  When you feel downgrading php or joomla is a solution, seek another solution.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you for suggestion, You are right 100%, I edited comment to reflect your point.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this has occured for me I have **overwritten all of the files with the original Joomla! files** and that has resolved the problem.  Hours of troubleshooting and a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache, then close your browser and reopen it that fixed it for me.

Clearing cache in every browser and/or device is different but here is a helpful website with instructions for each browser.

https://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/

Answer (score 0):

If trying the other solutions on this page didn't solve your problem (for users who end up with this topic), you also should check if your file permissions are correct.

In my case the file 'configuration.php' didn't have the right permissions.
It should be 644.

IF you still can login, but are unable to login with another username or browser, you should check:

System -> System information -> Folder permissions

They all must be writable, so if you see a red item in the list, you should set the permissions of that particular file to 644 (only the owner of the file - Apache / NGINX, should be able to write).