# Admin does not log in or error

Tags: administrator, login

Admin does not log in, and it does not error.  It just seems to refresh.

I have tried everything in this post: [Can't log in with admin, no error messages](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/22549/cant-log-in-with-admin-no-error-messages)

- I have tried overwriting all of the core files via FTP
- plg_user_joomla is enabled
- I have changed my PHP version from 7.3 to 7.2 and 7.1
- Nothing is set for the cookie domain in configuration.php error reporting is set to maximum
- I have changed the password to check that is correct but it is not saying incorrect password
- If I put an incorrect password, it does not tell me that error message
- I have disabled Admin Tools
- I have checked plg_authentication_joomla and it is enabled
- I have renamed .htaccess

Worst of all it was all working last night when I left the office!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleared the cache on my browser and that fixed my issue.

Clearing cache in every browser and/or device is different but here is a helpful website with instructions for each browser.

https://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/

If you only want to clear cache for this particular site you can go to inspect element or inspect, or whatever your browser calls it.  Then go to "storage" (in Firefox, others may call it a different name).  You can then clear cached storage and cookies for this particular site.